# Multiple List RecyclerView SQLitedatabase

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

[here's the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEELQ.png)

I have an app that makes the users' all his/her favorites placed on one place. So that he/she will not go through all the data. All I want is to have a recyclerview with multiple list that the "ListTitle" dynamically created, and when the "ListTitle" is already in it, only the child will appear. If not, create again another cardview. Thanks in advance.

My Code:

LoadsFavoriteAdapter.java

```
public class LoadFavoritesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LoadFavoritesAdapter.LoadFavoritesViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<LoadFavorites> loadFavorites;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<LoadFavorites> mloadFavorites;

final String loadParent = "";

public LoadFavoritesAdapter(ArrayList<LoadFavorites> loadFavorites, Context context){
    this.loadFavorites = loadFavorites;
    this.context = context;
    this.mloadFavorites = loadFavorites;
}

public class LoadFavoritesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView txtLoadNameTest, txtLoadAmountTest;

    public LoadFavoritesViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        txtLoadAmountTest = view.findViewById(R.id.txtLoadAmountTest);
        txtLoadNameTest = view.findViewById(R.id.txtLoadNameTest);
    }
}

public LoadFavoritesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.favorite_item, parent, false);

    return new LoadFavoritesViewHolder(itemView);
}

public void onBindViewHolder(final LoadFavoritesViewHolder holder, int position){
    holder.txtLoadNameTest.setText(loadFavorites.get(position).getLoadName());
    holder.txtLoadAmountTest.setText(loadFavorites.get(position).getLoadAmount());
}

public int getItemCount(){
    return mloadFavorites.size();
}}
```

Favorites.java

```
public class Favorites extends AppCompatActivity {

Database localDb;
Context CTX = this;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<LoadFavorites> loadFavorites;
private LoadFavoritesAdapter loadFavoritesAdapter;
private Database database;
private ArrayList<LoadFavorites> mloadFavorites;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorites);

    localDb = new Database(this);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_favorites);

    loadFavorites = new ArrayList<>();
    loadFavoritesAdapter = new LoadFavoritesAdapter(loadFavorites, this);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(loadFavoritesAdapter);
    database = new Database(this);

    getDataFromSQLite();

}

private void getDataFromSQLite(){
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
            loadFavorites.clear();
            loadFavorites.addAll(database.getFavorites());

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid){
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }.execute();
}}
```

Database.java

public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

```
private static final String DB_NAME="Favorites.db";
private static final int DB_VER=1;

public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);


    try{
        String myPath = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(); // also check the extension of you db file
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        if(dbfile.exists()){
        Toast.makeText(context, "database exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(context, ""+myPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "cant find database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(context, ""+myPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e){
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    }
}

public void addToFavorites(String loadId, String loadName, String loadDetail, String loadNumber, String loadDuration, String loadAmount, String loadParent){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("INSERT INTO Favorites(LoadId, LoadName, LoadDetail, LoadNumber, LoadDuration, LoadAmount, LoadParent) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');", loadId, loadName, loadDetail, loadNumber, loadDuration, loadAmount, loadParent);
    db.execSQL(query);
}

public void removeFromFavorites(String loadId){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("DELETE FROM Favorites WHERE LoadId='%s';", loadId);
    db.execSQL(query);
}

public boolean isFavorite(String loadId){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM Favorites WHERE LoadId='%s';", loadId);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return true;
}

public Cursor getInformation(Database database){
    SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    String[] columns = {"LoadId", "LoadParent"};

    String sqlTable = "Favorites";
    qb.setTables(sqlTable);

    Cursor CR = qb.query(db,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    return CR;
}

public List<LoadFavorites> getFavorites(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect = {"LoadId", "LoadName", "LoadDetail", "LoadNumber", "LoadDuration", "LoadAmount", "LoadParent"};
    String sqlTable = "Favorites";

    qb.setTables(sqlTable);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db,sqlSelect,null,null,null,null,null);

    final List<LoadFavorites> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            result.add(new LoadFavorites(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LoadId")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LoadName")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LoadDetail")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LoadNumber")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LoadDuration")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LoadAmount")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LoadParent"))
                    ));
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    return result;
}}
```

Comment: what's issue?is it crashed?

Comment: There's no issue, All I want is to display multiple list in one recyclerview, dynamically